# SQL comma separated value in IN clause case statement error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm encountering an error on the item below and I don't understand why. Can anyone shed some light on it for me?

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_AcMonthOrder
(
    @Month varchar(100)
)
RETURNS INT 
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @MonthOrder Int 
    SET @MonthOrder = 
        (CASE 
        WHEN @Month IN ('Aug','August',8) THEN 1 
        WHEN @Month IN ('Sep','September',9) THEN 2 
        WHEN@Month IN ('Oct','October',10) THEN 3 
        ...
        ELSE 0 END)
    RETURN @MonthOrder
END
```

If I attempt to call this function then it works fine for an integer, but not for the varchars. I.e. PRINT @dbo.fn_AcMonthOrder(8) will return 1 as expected, but PRINT @dbo.fn_AcMonthOrder('Aug') Or PRINT @dbo.fn_AcMonthOrder('August') returns the following error:

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Aug' to data type int.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use different data types in an expression, SQL Server follows [data type precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx).  In this case:

```
8 IN ('Aug','August', 8)
```

You're mixing `int` with `varchar`.  Since `int` has higher precedence, it will convert the `varchar` to `int`.  The reason this particular case does not throw an error might be optimization.  This does throw an error:

```
8 IN ('Aug','August',10)
```

And this does not throw an error:

```
'Aug' IN ('Aug','August',8)
```

But this throws an error again:

```
'Sept' IN ('Aug','August',8)
```

This confirms that the optimizer first compares the elements that do not require conversion.  It only raises an error when it gets to the elements it cannot convert.

At the end of the day, the best solution is to make sure all data types are the same.  In your case, you could just list the numbers as a string:

```
WHEN @Month IN ('Aug','August','8') THEN 1 
                              ^^^^^
```

Comment: Thank you for flagging the data type precedence - I did manage to set this, just by messing around - but I'll be digging into that later.

Answer (score 1):

```
        WHEN @Month IN ('Aug','August','8') THEN 1 
        WHEN @Month IN ('Sep','September','9') THEN 2 
        WHEN@Month IN ('Oct','October','10') THEN 3
```

Enclose in single quotes month values in numbers eg change 8 to '8' .
This is because @Month is  of VARCHAR() datatype and IN() clause requires values inside it must have compatible datatype conversion amongst them.

Answer (score 1):

All the elements in the IN-list have to be of a type where implicit conversion is possible. You cannot convert a varchar value to an integer one, but the other way round. So try this statement.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_AcMonthOrder
(
  @Month varchar(100)
)
RETURNS INT AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @MonthOrder Int
  SET @MonthOrder =
    (CASE
      WHEN @Month IN ('Aug','August','8') THEN 1
      WHEN @Month IN ('Sep','September','9') THEN 2
      WHEN@Month IN ('Oct','October','10') THEN 3
      ELSE 0
    END)
  RETURN @MonthOrder
END
```

Comment: Thanks Scoregraphic - this did fix the error, but I felt that the answer from andomar has more detail (about data type precedence and optimization)

Answer (score 1):

When you use IN clause you should use one DataType now your are using **'Aug'** near **8**, and it assumes that it should convert 'aug',... to int it is incorrect.
you can write it in this way (Do it for all you Case Whens)

```
WHEN @Month IN ('Aug','August','8') THEN 1 
.....
```